# How to change a col in R function of index

Tags: r, tidyverse

Imagine you have this data:

```
a<- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 1)
```

How can I get, automatically a new column (b) with the same values (but one file displacement)

In order to get:

```
b <- c(0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9)
```

In b, the first value is new (0) and the last value of "a" (1) is lost
But, I want to obtain (b)

Answer (score 5):

Probably `lag` from `dplyr` package

```
> dplyr::lag(a, default = 0)
[1] 0.0 0.2 0.3 0.7 0.9
```

or `shift` from `data.table`

```
> data.table::shift(a, fill = 0)
[1] 0.0 0.2 0.3 0.7 0.9
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add 0 and remove the last element of your vector like this:

```r
a<- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 1) 
b = c(0, a[-length(a)])
b
#> [1] 0.0 0.2 0.3 0.7 0.9
```

And a shorter option from @ThomasIsCoding (thanks!):

```r
a<- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 1) 
b = c(0, head(a, -1))
b
#> [1] 0.0 0.2 0.3 0.7 0.9
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>